# Merging a double summation into a single one

Tags: summation

I'm looking for merging this summations into a single one:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^k{\sum_{j=0}^i{b^j}}$ where $b$ is an integer.

I know it is equal to:
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^k{b^i(k-i+1)}$

In fact, one can see that:
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^k{\sum_{j=0}^i{b^j}} = (b^0) + (b^0 + b^1) + (b^0 + b^1 + b^2) + ... + (b^0 + b^1 + b^2 + ... + b^k)$, where any $b^j$ appears from $i=j$ to $i=k$ in such a way that it can be found $k-j+1$ times.

However, I would like to know a more rigorous demonstration, i.e. in a more "closed" form, without involving these ellipsis.

Comment: The summation is over $0\le j\le i\le k$ so the $b^j$ coefficient is $\sum_{i=j}^k1=k-j+1$.

Comment: I don't understand how you came up with $\sum_{i=j}^{k}1$.

Comment: Each such $i$ contributes $1$ to the coefficient through a monic monomial term.